# Jquery code performance on '.on' method

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does the following code make any impact on application's performance?

```
$("body").on('click','#id',function () {
   //code to be executed
});
```

if so, could any one please explain why?

Comment: Yes - but an infinitesimal one. Probably single figure milliseconds. Instead of the event being trapped on the `#id` element directly you have to wait for the event to bubble up to the `body` element. Note that this difference is not caused by the use of `on()` directly, but because you're using a delegated event handler.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!,  so what would be the alternate for this in order to target future elements?

Comment: There isn't one - the code you have used is the best for this purpose.

Comment: Okey, in that case if i use the nearest parent's Id instead of 'body' would help the performance?

Comment: Yes, that would follow best practice

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks for clearing me dude :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but slight. The reason is that it would capture *every* click on the document's `body`, then evaluate whether that bubbled up from `#id`, and exit if it is not. It is a good policy to attach the handler to the most tightly defined element that will contain all of your events, as you rarely need to go as wide as `body` - for example, `$("#stuffgoeshere").on('click','#id',function...)`. And if you actually know the ID of the element and that element exists, it would be even better to attach the handler directly to the element, using `$('#id').on('click', function...)`.

Comment: thanks for the answer,  if my understanding is right, i can use the most nearest 'container's' id instead of 'body', right?